# Select and Display the table in oracle APEX mail body

Tags: oracle-apex

Is it possible to select and display the database table in `classic report` manner in mail body while sending the mail in `oracle APEX 4.2`?

**Version** : oracle APEX 4.2

**SAMPLE**  : [SAMPLE FORMAT FOR EMAIL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEKae.png)

Regards,
DOC

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Suppose I have `EMP` table and I want to select the table and publish the table in the mail body.
`select ename, dname from emp where dno=10` and when mail is recieved, the mail body should publish  the `ename` and `dname` in table format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, by sending an HTML email - but you have to construct the HTML yourself.  For example:

```
declare
   l_body_text long;
   l_body_html long;
begin
   l_body_html := '<table style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black"><tbody>'
                  || '<tr>'
                  || '<th style="background-color: #eef; border: 1px solid black">ENAME</th>'
                  || '<th style="background-color: #eef; border: 1px solid black">DNAME</th></tr>';

   for r in (select ename, dname from emp)
   loop
      l_body_html := l_body_html || '<tr><td style="border: 1px solid black">' 
                     || r.ename || '</td><td style="border: 1px solid black">'
                     || r.dname|| '</td></tr>';
   end loop;
   l_body_html := l_body_html || '</tbody></table>';

   l_body_text := 'Plain text version';

   apex_mail.send
      ( p_to        => 'you@there.com'
      , p_from      => 'me@here.com'
      , p_body      => l_body_text
      , p_body_html => l_body_html
      , p_subj      => 'Your report'
      );
end;
```

Note:

1. You need to supply a plain text alternative in case the recipient cannot receive HTML emails.
2. You need to apply any styling in-line - you cannot reference a CSS file.

Comment: How can i add images from table based on some condition? Suppose image is stored in table and needs to be displayed for a particualr condition, i.e. dynamic and not a fixed image.

Comment: @Vini I think you should raise this as a new question, giving more details of what you want to do.

Comment: I have raised a thread detailing the entire requirement and would be nice of you if you can take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65228718/oracle-apex-send-designed-greetings-email-with-html-images-and-text