# Is it possible to manipulate the database through mail in oracle apex?

Tags: email, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I was having the similar problem as mentioned in the below link, [Select and Display the table in oracle APEX mail body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324617/select-and-display-the-table-in-oracle-apex-mail-body). I followed the mentioned steps and it worked!! .

Now, I just want to extend the same question and wanted to know, Is it possible to manipulate the the database through click on the button in the mail?

If I crate the html Button **APPROVE**, It should be able to manipulate database table.
Suppose, **APPROVE** performs delete operation: `delete ename from emp where dno=10`.

**VERSION** : `ORACLE APEX 4.2`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending an HTML email to a user and you want that user to interact with the system from the email, you could generate an [HTML form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) that submits to a particular URL (some APEX page with some set of parameters) that actually implements the `DELETE`.

Assuming that the client email application would allow the user to submit a form, which would generally be a security issue and would probably not be possible from some clients, you'd probably have security issues to worry about on the server side.  I'd assume, for example, that you don't want to allow any random person that works out the URL to call to be able to delete whatever row you want from your system.  You probably want to require that someone is logged in before you'd allow them to delete a row.  And you probably want to make sure that they have permission to delete that particular row.

It's certainly possible that you could work around both the client and the server side permission issues by doing something like creating a unique token that expires after a short period of time and gets passed in with the form to verify that the user has permission to delete that particular row.  But by the time you're building that sort of infrastructure or sending users to a login page, you're probably better off just creating links in your email that point to a page in your application and letting users go there to request the actual delete.  That's going to work more reliably than a form that submits a request and it will probably involve less work for you.